# Limsup of a sequence is greater then the limsup of a subsequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limsup-and-liminf

Consider a sequence of real numbers $\{a_n\}_n$. Let $\{a_{n_j}\}_j$ be a subsequence of $\{a_n\}_n$. Suppose I have shown that $\limsup_{j \rightarrow \infty} a_{n_j}=L$ with $|L|<\infty$. Is it true that $\limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_{n}\geq L$?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: You can proof this by contradiction if you want to check it rigorously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition $\limsup_{n\to\infty}\, a_n$  is the greatest number that you can achieve with a convergent subsequence of $\{a_n\}$. Since $\{a_{n_j}\}$ is a subsequence of $\{a_n\}$ we have that every subsequence of $\{a_{n_j}\}$ is a subsequence of $\{a_n\}$. Therefore 
$$\limsup_{n\to\infty}\, a_n\geq \limsup_{n\to\infty}\, a_{n_j}$$
because of the $\sup$'s properties.

Comment: This characterization is not always taken as the definition, one can even guess that it was not for the OP if they are asking this question (but who knows). Anyway, please use `\limsup_{n\to\infty}`.